# Changing a value to N/A

Tags: r, na

I did a questionnaire research where some of the answers were "I don't know" and "I don't want to answer". Now I need to change those answering options to "N/A" so that they won't be accounted for in my statistical analyses. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty easy to accomplish.  I am making some assumptions about your data, since you didn't provide the format.  Let's assume that you have your data in an excel spreadsheet and you have imported it into R with the following code:

```
## Import Data ##
require("gdata")
myData <-read.xls("myData.xlsx", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Ok, now you have a data frame in R called `myData`.  Let's assume that there is a column called `Answers` which contains the responses as strings.  We have some good responses, some NA values, and some that say "I don't know" or "I don't want to answer" or similar.

**This code will change any answers that start with "I don't" to NA.**

```
myData$Answers[startsWith(myData$Answers,"I don't")] <- NA
```

**Or you could specify each NA answer individually**
(such as if there are some good answers that start with "I don't").

```
myData$Answers[myData$Answers == "I don't know")] <- NA
myData$Answers[myData$Answers == "I don't want to answer")] <- NA
```

**Or you can change all answers that contain a specific phrase anywhere in their answer to NA**

```
myData$Answers[grepl("don't know", myData$Answers)] <- NA
```

If you imported strings as factors then the code above would change like this:

```
myData$Answers[grepl("don't know", levels(myData$Answers))] <- NA
```